# How do I use the Type from my List<Type>?

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics

I would like to make my code convention-based by using Types and keeping things simple, but generics has it's own complexity with it's own learning curve.

I have a bunch of POCOs (Plain Old CLR Objects) in a List that I'd like to iterate through later in the code.

```
var models = new List<Type>();
models.Add(typeof(Person));
models.Add(typeof(Company));
```

Would like to cycle through each list item:

```
models.ForEach(m =>
{
    var label = m.FullName;
    // var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<typeof(m)>>(""); // doesn't work
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<m>>(""); // doesn't work either
    ...
}
```

The issue is that the "m" in the Deserialize line isn't working.  What would be the best way to pass that through, i.e. making the 'List<m>' a 'List<T>' that we can use?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have to use some `Reflection` to call the generic method `DeserializeObject<T>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use generics, you really need to know the Type (`T`) at *compile time*, you don't - you know it at *run time*. (Caveat: Its possible with reflection, but theres no need to use it when there's an overload as described below)

There is an [overload of `DeserializeObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) which takes a `Type` rather than use generics. So your code would be

```
models.ForEach(m =>
{
    var label = m.FullName;
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("",m);
    ...
}
```

However, as you've pointed out in comments you actually need a `List<T>` not a single `T`. You'll need a *little bit* of reflection, just to create the right type to pass to the above `DeserializeObject` call.

```
var tList = typeof(List<>);  // Type of open List
models.ForEach(m =>
{
    var label = m.FullName;
    var tConvert = = tList.MakeGenericType(m); 
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("",tConvert);
    ...
}
```

---

The answer to your question is above, but the more I look at it the harder it is to see what you can actually *do* with `data`. all you'll ***ever*** know about `data` is that it is an `object`. You cant cast it to anything - you wont know if its a list of `Person` or a list of `Company`.

Perhaps this was an overly contrived example you've used for a real-life problem. If not I forsee you're next problem is what to do with `data`!!

Comment: didn't know about such an overload, if there was not such a one, reflection would have been the only solution, although we can use Delegate to improve the speed a little.

Comment: @KingKing - I dont follow. There ***is*** the required overload, although I cant link directly to it due to the poor documentation structure of that class

Comment: I believe @KingKing is just saying `models.ForEach(delegate (Type m){var label = m.FullName;var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("", m);});`

Comment: But that just wouldnt make sense. Thats the old fashioned syntax before we had lambda's (`m => ....`)

Comment: @paqogomez no that's not what I mean. I've never used `delegate` since `lambda` was born, I mean the class `Delegate`, we can use the `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to improve the speed of reflection when using MethodInfo directly.

Comment: It actually need to return a List<m>, not just m.  It's good to know that there is an overload tho'!

Comment: I'm using data for generic stuff like counting the number of records.  There are better/different ways to do things tho', however when I was coding this it felt like a great mental challenge that should be discussed and find a resolution for.  Successfully implemented! Thanks again @Jamiec and all who joined in!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the type at compile time you can do this with Reflection. Consider the following code:

```
models.ForEach(m =>
{
    var mi = JsonConvert.GetType()
                        .GetMethod("DeserializeObject");
    var m = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { m });

    // you pass [null] for the object because it's a [static] method
    // and you don't have to declare [args] if you can express it simply
       // but keep in mind that it's simply an object[]
    m.Invoke(null, args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to call the generic method using reflection (if there isn't any overload that takes the type as parameter)

```
models.ForEach(m =>
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(JsonConvert).GetMethod("DeserializeObject");
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(m);
    generic.Invoke(null, "");
}
```